# Springboot error 404 after login with thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

When I try to login with username and password springboot redirects me to the right page : `home`, in this case, but instead of showing me that page returns a `404` error. These are my first attempts with springboot so maybe I'm missing basic stuffs.

This is my `login` page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/login.css" th:href="@{/css/login.css}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>

        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="form-container">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li style="display: inline;"><a><img src="../static/images/nft4all.png" th:src="@{/images/nft4all.png}"></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <form name = "f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                <label for="username"></label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">

                <label for="password"></label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">

                <button type="submit">Accedi</button>
                <a th:href="@{/register}" href="registration.html" > oppure registrati </a>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Authconfiguration page :

```
public class AuthConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // authorization paragraph: qui definiamo chi può accedere a cosa
                .authorizeRequests()

                // chiunque (autenticato o no) può accedere alle pagine index, login, register, ai css e alle immagini
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/",
                        "/index",
                        "/login",
                        "/collection/*",
                        "/collections",
                        "/NFTS",
                        "/signup_form",
                        "/register",
                        "/css/**", 
                        "zzz",
                        "/images/**").permitAll()

                // chiunque (autenticato o no) può mandare richieste POST al punto di accesso per login e register
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login", "/register").permitAll()

                // solo gli utenti autenticati con ruolo ADMIN possono accedere a risorse con path /admin/**
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)

                // tutti gli utenti autenticati possono accere alle pagine rimanenti
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                // login paragraph: qui definiamo come è gestita l'autenticazione
                // usiamo il protocollo formlogin
                .and().formLogin()

                // la pagina di login si trova a /login
                // NOTA: Spring gestisce il post di login automaticamente
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")      
                //.loginProcessingUrl("/process_login")
                // se il login ha successo, si viene rediretti al path /default
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home",true)
                .failureUrl("/loginPage?error")
                .permitAll()

                // logout paragraph: qui definiamo il logout
                .and().logout()

                // il logout è attivato con una richiesta GET a "/logout"
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))

                // in caso di successo, si viene reindirizzati alla /index page

                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true).permitAll();
```

And this is the controller, we shouldn't need it because I read that springboot handles `post` methods on `login` page but I will put it here just to be sure.

```
public class RegController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CredentialsService credentialService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("credentials", new Credentials());
        return "register";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String processRegister(@ModelAttribute("credentials")Credentials credentials,@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        credentials.setUser(user);
        credentialService.saveCredentials(credentials);
        return "login";
    }

}
```

I'm sure `home` file exists because I see it here : [image]

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add a new controller that reads "/home" and returns "home.html"